# Stripe checkout session billing address autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am using stripe checkout session in test mode, but I am facing an issue since the last few hours, the billing address autocomplete no longer works.

I've checked my browser's console log and it seems there is an issue with

```
https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/js/checkout-inner-address-autocomplete-bbf777a7937baf9e86cab51f02584c91.js
```

I get the following error in my browser's console :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not a function
    E
    Onload
```

It seems the error comes from stripe's source code. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I was seeing this issue too but it looks like Autocomplete is working again for me. Are you still seeing this error?

Comment: Yes. It seems stripe fixed the error.